# Connecting my flask with the mongodb Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am trying to connect my docker container running the gunicorn with another container of mongodb.
This is my Dockerfile for building the container

```
FROM python:3.8.10-buster
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config 
RUN apt install -y libsm6 libxext6
RUN apt-get install -y libxrender-dev
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./gunicorn.sh"]
EXPOSE 4444
ENTRYPOINT ["./gunicorn.sh"]
```

I created the following docker-compose.yml for running the built container

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: 'flask/flask_docker'
    container_name: 'xyz'
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
```

Following is the docker-compose for the Mongodb

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
    image: 'mongo:3.6.8'
    container_name: 'transactionsDB'
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=abc
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=abc
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc@v_1
    ports:
      - '5555:27017'
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/abc/:/data/db
```

I used the following as the connection string from flask to connect with the mongodb

```
mongodb://abc:abc@v_1@transactionsDB:5555/abc
```

But everytime I get the following error `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError`

Comment: First, those services are in different network so they can't connect to each other, put them together on one docker-compose file. And your connection string isn't correct, it should be `mongodb://service_name:service_host@username:password...`

Comment: @tuan.tran I don't think connection URI is a problem https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ .  So I cannot connect to the container on the different network at all?

Comment: yes, you can't, it is similar to you connect between 2 computer in different LAN without internet